# In Bash: "source" a (dynamically) created script, without use of a temporary file

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Example, for your amusement:

```
$ f=/etc/os-release; . $f; cat $f | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/'
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$NAME" "$NAME"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$VERSION" "$VERSION"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$ID" "$ID"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$ID_LIKE" "$ID_LIKE"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$PRETTY_NAME" "$PRETTY_NAME"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$VERSION_ID" "$VERSION_ID"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$HOME_URL" "$HOME_URL"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$SUPPORT_URL" "$SUPPORT_URL"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$BUG_REPORT_URL" "$BUG_REPORT_URL"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$PRIVACY_POLICY_URL" "$PRIVACY_POLICY_URL"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$VERSION_CODENAME" "$VERSION_CODENAME"
printf "%20s: %s\n" "\$UBUNTU_CODENAME" "$UBUNTU_CODENAME"
$
```

... now the actual problem;
how do I execute this in the local shell, WITHOUT the use of a temporary file!?
(so avoid anything similar to `...  >z ; . z ; rm z`)

xargs cannot do it (IIUC)
source - has no such option
bash - creates a subshell, so will not see the variable values.

**Things I've tried:**

```
$ source <(f=/etc/os-release; . $f; cat $f | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
               $NAME: 
            $VERSION: 
                 $ID: 
            $ID_LIKE: 
        $PRETTY_NAME: 
         $VERSION_ID: 
           $HOME_URL: 
        $SUPPORT_URL: 
     $BUG_REPORT_URL: 
 $PRIVACY_POLICY_URL: 
   $VERSION_CODENAME: 
    $UBUNTU_CODENAME: 

$ source < <(f=/etc/os-release; . $f; cat $f | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
 
$ source /dev/fd/0 <(f=/etc/os-release; . $f; cat $f | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
^C  # no output, CTRL-C
$
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT, and I repeat - without use of temporary file/scripts:

```
               $NAME: Ubuntu
            $VERSION: 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
                 $ID: ubuntu
            $ID_LIKE: debian
        $PRETTY_NAME: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
         $VERSION_ID: 20.04
           $HOME_URL: https://www.ubuntu.com/
        $SUPPORT_URL: https://help.ubuntu.com/
     $BUG_REPORT_URL: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/
 $PRIVACY_POLICY_URL: https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy
   $VERSION_CODENAME: focal
    $UBUNTU_CODENAME: focal
```

---

## Explanation:

In my version [above] of this (a copy from @Scott's answer, below) I do not have the variables from /etc/os-release initialized in the main shell, only in the subshell. And of that follows that they cannot be printed by the `source <(...)` in the main shell.

So a working "corrected" version of the oneliner is:

```
f=/etc/os-release; source "$f"; source <( sed <"$f" -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
```

Where the first `source "$f";` initializes the variables, then the subshell produces the code to be executed by `source <(...)` .
above
*... with the short `.`  replaced by `source`  for readability, here.*

Comment: [shell - Feed source command with a pipe - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176873/feed-source-command-with-a-pipe)

Comment: Strange, I cannot determine a way to achieve the above from that posting. What am I missing...

Comment: The use of `echo` - it's the only way you can do it without a temp file

Comment: I have been hacking on this thing with variants of echo, can't get my head to produce anything that actually works. Leaving it for now... too late in the evening.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not understand how your echo -comment (even with the linked posting) should have made me find the problem... :-} *shrug*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short/general answer:

The first thing you tried was correct: 
if *`command-list`* is a list of commands that, when run,
outputs a shell script (i.e., another list of commands),
you can execute the (dynamically created) script
with

```
source <(command-list)
```

or

```
. <(command-list)
```

In fact, in your example, it worked correctly. 
It didn’t give you the results you wanted because …

#### Long/specific answer:

… things like `$(…)` and `<(…)` 
(and, for that matter, `(…)` ) create subshells. 
The problem with the first thing you tried
is that you’re doing the `. $f` in the subshell
and you’re *executing* the `printf` commands in the outer shell. 
So the solution is that
you need to do the **`.`** in the outer shell:

```
f=/etc/os-release; . "$f"; source <(cat "$f" | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
```

I added double quotes around `"$f"` because it’s **The Right Thing To Do**™;
as long as the value of `$f` contains no funky characters,
you don’t, strictly speaking, need them. 
And, “of course”, you can change the `source` in the above
to another **`.`**:

```
f=/etc/os-release; . "$f"; . <(cat "$f" | sed -re 's/(.*)=.*/printf "%20s: %s\\n" "\\$\1" "$\1"/')
```

I left the UUOC for you to fix.

Comment: IMHO quotes and UUOC is excused in cases where you're not producing "production-code", all you see here is numerous attempts to understand the situation. Well, I believe I got it now... I have - all over this - been missing the fact; the problem is created by a more severe subshell -issue than I was aware of.

Comment: Now, I ask; will this be worth reading for others?

Comment: Short about UUOC: `cat $f | sed ...` instead of `sed <$f ...`

Comment: (hmm... "severe" is an overstatement)